# How to create a panel of buttons using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating an animation that plays according to the speed and the color of the user's choice. I need to create a panel of speeds and colors, but I am not really sure how to crate it using JavaScript. I am only familiar with `form` in HTML. Maybe I can use

```
for (i=0; i<=51; ++i){

creates buttons
}
```

But I am not totally sure, and how to assign corresponding speed and colors.

I need something like this:

[image]

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes it seems like you want to create a form with JS? I would start with reading about [`innerHtml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is great but I do recommend to dive into pure HTML, actually many many components are already built-in for most use cases.

In your logic you are creating as many elements as the answer, but we can use the input type="number", or type="range" to do the same thing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/HTML5_input_types

From there, retrieving the values in realtime from JavaScript will be easily done by passing an ID. Doing so is great because it **forces to separate the logic and the templating.**

```js
// @Param a   String   Mandatory   Name
// @Param b   Int      Mandatory   Count
// @Param c   Array    Mandatory   Element names
// @Param d   Bool     Optionnal   Show count in name (default false)
function radioSet(a, b, c, d = false){   
  document.body.append(Object.assign(document.createElement("form"), {id: a}));
  let e = document.getElementById(a);
  for (let i = 0; i < b; i++){
    e.append(Object.assign(document.createElement("label"), {textContent: (d) ? c[i] + " "  + i : c[i]}),
             Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {type: "radio", value: (d) ? c[i] + " "  + i : c[i], name: "assigned"})
    )         
  }
  document.body.append(Object.assign(document.createElement("hr"), {}));
  e.addEventListener("input", () => console.log(a + " change! " + e.assigned.value) )
}


radioSet("speed", 51, Array(51).fill("Speed"), true)
radioSet("color", 3, ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"])
```

If you feel stuck retrieving the values, I will extend the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to stick to JavaScript for creating 51 radios for speed and 3 radios for color with corresponding speed and color.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you so much! It is also easy to follow and understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the button and append:

```js
for (i = 0; i <= 51; ++i) {
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Button" + i;
  document.body.appendChild(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.createElement` API for this.

```js
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('some-id');

for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
  const radio = document.createElement('radio');
  radio.innerHTML = `Speed ${i}`;
  parentDiv.appendChild(radio);
}
```